# How to Put value of a array in variable with the same name

Tags: php, arrays

I have written some codes :

```
$params = func_get_args();
$title = $params[1]['title'];
$writer = $params[1]['writer'];
$magname = $params[1]['magname'];
$confname = $params[1]['confname'];
$magyear = $params[1]['magyear'];
$confyear = $params[1]['confyear'];
$subject = $params[1]['subject'];
$scredit = $params[1]['scredit'];
$lang = $params[1]['lang'];
$keywords = $params[1]['keywords'];
$pyear = $params[1]['pyear'];
.....
```

Is it possile to do it with a loop ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should do it:

```
extract($params[1]);
```